# Getting error in Appium "iproxy exited with code '208'" and app not getting launched on iOS mobile

Tags: java, react-native-ios, mobile-application, appium-ios

On Mac machine using IOS real device 12.2 version the native app gets installed but does not launch and I could see error in Appium logs.
Appium Version:1.10.0
Xcode version: 10.2
IOS version 12.2

I am currently creating basic framework for mobile app testing

No solution found online.

```
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.2");
        caps.setCapability("xcodeOrgid", "TCKV8EY4B5");
        caps.setCapability("xcodeSigningid", "iPhone Developer");
        caps.setCapability("bundleId", "de.cgi.le.flinc");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pooja iPhone");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "388f03938c82b5bc39313e6c8ffb6d7802dd9dbd");
        caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        //caps.setCapability("useNewWDA",true);
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```